# Problems with the english language in a logical statement (plural implies distinctness)

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I don't want to make this to general because I think I would make a mistake then but I think one can generalize this idea for every uniqueness/injectivity proof:

The claim is:

$V$ vector space over $F\wedge B$ basis of $V$ $\Rightarrow\forall v\in V\exists !(B_v,c):B_v\subseteq B\wedge B_v \text{ finite }  \wedge c:B_v\rightarrow F\backslash\{0\}\wedge v=\sum_{b\in B_v}c(b)b$

My first question is what is the actual logical definition of $\exists!$ ?

To prove the uniqueness I think we have to show the implication

$\exists(B_v,c),(\bar{B_v},\bar{c}):B_v\subseteq B\wedge B_v \text{ finite }  \wedge c:B_v\rightarrow F\backslash\{0\}\wedge \bar{B_v}\subseteq B\wedge \bar{B}_v \text{ finite }  \wedge \bar{c}:\bar{B_v}\rightarrow F\backslash\{0\}\wedge \big((B_v,c)=(\bar{B_v},\bar{c})\vee (B_v,c)\neq(\bar{B_v},\bar{c})\big)\wedge v=\sum_{b\in B_v}c(b)b=\sum_{b\in \bar{B}_v}\bar{c}(b)b\Rightarrow (B_v,c)=(\bar{B_v},\bar{c})$

But I don't know how we would transcribe this statement to English because in my head I think about:

*If we have two pairs that are in the solutionset (i.e that fulfill desired qualities) and the pairs might be different or equal then the pairs are equal*

The problem I have here is that if I say two pairs then I automatically think about two **different** pairs. So how can we reformulate the statement, i.e. what are we proving here in English? How can I express it?

Comment: $\exists !$ means "There is exactly one"

Comment: No I mean the logical definition of $\exists!$ only using $\forall,\exists,\wedge,\vee$ and statementvariables

Comment: Ah!  OK, I showed some ways to do that in my Answer

Comment: What you are "thinking in your head" is exactly the way to think about it, and write it. A mathematician reading "two pairs" would  are _not_ automatically think they are different. English is _much_ better than formal logic for this kind of argument.

Answer (score 1):

$\exists !$ means "There is exactly one", so that expresses uniqueness right there.

Without using $\exists !$, you can use several strategies:

First, we can express that there is one .. and no *other* one. So, you would get something like:

$\exists c (bla \ bla \ bla (c) \land \neg \exists c' (c' \not = c \land bla \ bla \ bla(c')))$

We can also say that there is one with the property, and everything that has the property must equal that first one:

$\exists c (bla \ bla \ bla (c) \land \forall c' ( bla \ bla \ bla(c') \to c'  = c))$

Finally, we can use this structure:

$\exists c \forall c' (bla \ bla \ bla (c') \leftrightarrow c'  = c))$

See how this last one works?  When $c'  =c$, the right side holds true, and hence we must have $bla \ bla \ bla (c')$, and since $c'=c$ we thus have $bla \ bla \ bla (c)$. And for any $c' \not = c$, the right side is false, and ehnce the left side should be false too, and hence we have $\neg bla \ bla \ bla (c')$ for any $c' \not = c$

Comment: It looks like that none of those templates fit to the proof that I did. I think what I did is more combinatoric, it does not really make sense what I wrote: $\exists c(\text{bla bla bla}(c))\wedge \exists c'(blablabla(c'))\Rightarrow c=c'$ or is this also equivalant to those definitions you have proposed?

Comment: Another common rendering of $\exists! x, \phi(x)$ is $(\exists x, \phi(x)) \wedge (\forall x \forall y, \phi(x) \wedge \phi(y) \rightarrow x = y)$.